# flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, build, archive

I have made a lot of changes to my flutter app including updating packages to their latest/resolvable versions.
NOTE: My app builds perfectly fine in VScode when I run the app in `debug` and if I use `flutter run`. No problems there.

So, now it's time to archive and send my build to the Apple. I would normally do this by opening up Xcode, archiving my latest build and then using `Xcode Organiser` to `Distribute App`.

Problem is, the build fails in Xcode before it can archive. I get these errors in Xcode:

```
/Users/joshua/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h /Users/joshua/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h: No such file or directory
```

```
/Users/joshua/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/messages.g.h /Users/joshua/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/messages.g.h: No such file or directory
```

```
/Users/joshua/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.17/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h /Users/joshua/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.17/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h: No such file or directory
```

I've tried, `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, deleting `/ios/Pods` and `/ios/podfile.lock`. Running `pod deintegrate` and `pod install --repo-update` from the `/ios` directory. I've tried running `rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`